# SimpleMultilineEntryElement insertion point failure

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm using the MonoTouch SimpleMultilineEntryElement from the [monotouch-element-pack](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-element-pack) (originally just MultilineEntryElement) and when I tap to insert somewhere in existing text, I can insert a single character and then the insertion point jumps to the end of the string. I've checked the sample application and the behaviour is the same so it appears to be something in the library rather than something I'm doing incorrectly. Has anyone else had this problem and resolved it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SimpleMultilineEntryElement change the FetchValue to the following, basically what is happening is the current position in the text is being lost with each modification of the text taking you to the end of the text each time.

With the following code you are saving the current position in the text at the start and repositioning the cursor at the end.

```
public void FetchValue() {
    if (entry == null) {
        return;
    }

    int currentPos = entry.SelectedRange.Location;
    var newValue = entry.Text;
    if (newValue == Value) {
        return;
    }

    Value = newValue;

    if (Changed != null) {
        Changed(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    if (currentPos > 0) {
        NSRange newPos = new NSRange(currentPos, 0);
        entry.SelectedRange = newPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is the issue, or if it can be an issue. But I thought entryKey and cellkey had to be unique to a specific element.  Both are set to MultilineEntryElement and not SimpleMultilineEntryElement.

Was thinking if you previously have used a MultilineEntryElement it could be getting dequeued in GetCell.

```
var cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell (CellKey);
```

Maybe...